# How to create animation for closed svg path

Tags: html, animation, svg, raphael

I am trying to create animation which fill a closed path with animation.

[image]

This is my svg which is creating the closed path:

```
<path fill="#000000" stroke="none" d="M238.281,174.573C248.449,182.844,238.12900000000002,206.155,231.52,212.05700000000002C200.11100000000002,240.12900000000002,134.22500000000002,267.20000000000005,108.39800000000001,227.258C93.47600000000001,204.17600000000002,101.91600000000001,168.55100000000002,114.97200000000001,146.37900000000002C116.486,143.92800000000003,118.766,145.484,117.98500000000001,147.34000000000003C98.50600000000001,185.34800000000004,111.37400000000001,227.41400000000004,159.306,221.95900000000003C181.185,219.30900000000003,209.638,208.14600000000004,227.34500000000003,195.38700000000003C229.59600000000003,193.76600000000002,232.37400000000002,191.73100000000002,233.86100000000002,190.31900000000002C221.52700000000002,185.90500000000003,190.156,189.51800000000003,184.19600000000003,173.717C181.19100000000003,165.74800000000002,187.25300000000001,149.83,191.19300000000004,141.62300000000002C204.02500000000003,114.91400000000002,232.57500000000005,89.94700000000002,246.48100000000005,109.65000000000002C249.32800000000006,113.77500000000002,251.90800000000004,135.63600000000002,245.71600000000007,135.63600000000002C242.66200000000006,131.55800000000002,239.34900000000007,124.93700000000003,233.48900000000006,124.93700000000003C218.73600000000005,125.04100000000003,197.39800000000005,138.88800000000003,194.57300000000006,151.45700000000002H194.58900000000006C193.58000000000007,155.217,196.46800000000005,160.871,199.48800000000006,163.04300000000003C209.489,170.251,229.978,167.669,238.281,174.573Z" stroke-width="1" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);fill: #fff;stroke: #000;" data-svg="path"></path>
```

This is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/utL00mu2/) of my path code.

Now I want to fill the closed path with a color with animation that will look like a progressed filling which will start from one terminal point and ends at the other point of the path. 
We tried with raphaeljs but any other js library is also fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Set a linear gradient as a fill and animate the stop of the gradient.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can you please help me giving some example?  or some jsfiddle example will be very helpful

Comment: I think it would be better if you read up on how linear gradients work now I've given you the hint about it. If you try it and get stuck, update the question with how far you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Robert says, a linear gradient may be one way. I'm just going to show another way which could be an alternative. You can improve the effect by making the path start at the point where the drawing start is desired.

One of the problems with your example vs typical path progression is that you have a variable width of the shape, so you can't do some of the usual tricks (like animatedasharray/offset). Some of the other methods may also not work very well, as fill doesn't have a direction. Linear gradient may help, but it could still have problems.

One other way could be to have a clip or mask and animate that.

In this example using Snap, we create a mask of an identical cloned element, find the length, make the stroke really fat (so the excess borders are contained by the mask), and then animate stroke-dashoffset to slowly draw the line.

It could be improved by just having a single path which is the desired single stroke (rather than the full closed shape), and also have the starting point of the path, the same as the desired animation start.

```js
var myPath = Snap('#myPath');

var myPathClone = myPath.clone().attr({ id:  'myPathClone' });

myPath.attr({ mask: myPathClone, fill: 'red' });

var myPathLength = myPathClone.getTotalLength();

myPathClone.attr({ fill: 'none', stroke: 'white', strokeWidth: 80, strokeDasharray: myPathLength + ' ' + myPathLength, strokeDashoffset: myPathLength, "stroke-linecap": 'round' });


myPathClone.animate({ strokeDashoffset: 0 }, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="mySvg" height="600" version="1.1" width="800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;"><desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.4</desc><defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs><path id="myPath" fill="#ff0000" stroke="none" d="M238.281,174.573C248.449,182.844,238.12900000000002,206.155,231.52,212.05700000000002C200.11100000000002,240.12900000000002,134.22500000000002,267.20000000000005,108.39800000000001,227.258C93.47600000000001,204.17600000000002,101.91600000000001,168.55100000000002,114.97200000000001,146.37900000000002C116.486,143.92800000000003,118.766,145.484,117.98500000000001,147.34000000000003C98.50600000000001,185.34800000000004,111.37400000000001,227.41400000000004,159.306,221.95900000000003C181.185,219.30900000000003,209.638,208.14600000000004,227.34500000000003,195.38700000000003C229.59600000000003,193.76600000000002,232.37400000000002,191.73100000000002,233.86100000000002,190.31900000000002C221.52700000000002,185.90500000000003,190.156,189.51800000000003,184.19600000000003,173.717C181.19100000000003,165.74800000000002,187.25300000000001,149.83,191.19300000000004,141.62300000000002C204.02500000000003,114.91400000000002,232.57500000000005,89.94700000000002,246.48100000000005,109.65000000000002C249.32800000000006,113.77500000000002,251.90800000000004,135.63600000000002,245.71600000000007,135.63600000000002C242.66200000000006,131.55800000000002,239.34900000000007,124.93700000000003,233.48900000000006,124.93700000000003C218.73600000000005,125.04100000000003,197.39800000000005,138.88800000000003,194.57300000000006,151.45700000000002H194.58900000000006C193.58000000000007,155.217,196.46800000000005,160.871,199.48800000000006,163.04300000000003C209.489,170.251,229.978,167.669,238.281,174.573Z" stroke-width="0" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-svg="path"></path><image x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="about:blank" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image><image x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="Raphaël’s object" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></image></svg>
```